# É possível definir o tamanho da fonte dinamicamente?

Tags: css

Estou tendo que desenvolver algumas *views*, e francamente definiria meu conhecimento de CSS como estrutural.

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um método, sem utilização de Javascript, de definir o tamanho da fonte a ser usada no texto dinamicamente.

#### Exemplo:

```html
<div class="text-20"> <!-- font-size : 20px; -->
</div>


<div class="text-25"> <!-- font-size : 25px; -->
</div>


<div class="text-15"> <!-- font-size : 15px; -->
</div>
```

Ou seja, basicamente a `class` seria `.text` e o `-{num}` correspondente ao tamanho da fonte.

Comment: Você quer que funcione com qualquer valor, sem definir as classes manualmente? Não dá. Mas você pode gerar o CSS para um determinado range de valores. Ou usar passos que façam sentido no design do site.

Comment: Compreendo, sim meu intuito era para qualquer valor, obrigado o auxilio, farei por javascript mesmo.

Comment: Por que você não simplesmente usa o estilo inline? <div style="font-size:20px"</div>?

Answer (score 0):

Você não demonstrou sua real necessidade, mas por que usar o class para fazer isso se você também pode usar o atributo "style" ?

```html
<div style="font-size:20px"></div>


<div style="font-size:25px"></div>


<div style="font-size:15px"></div>
```

Comment: Acho que isso não responde a pergunta. Ele quer especificar uma classe com um número e.g `texto-<?>`, onde`<?>` é o tamanho da fonte que deve renderizar o conteúdo esse elemento. Por exemplo: `<p class='texto-10'>foo</p>`, a palavra "foo" teria *10px*. `<p class='texto-100'>bar</p>`, a palavra "bar" teria *100px*... etc.

Comment: Eu entendi o que ele quer, mas como não deu muitos detalhes eu não entendi o porquê ele quer. Nem sempre as pessoas sabem oque realmente querem. Estamos aqui pra ajudar e sugerir. Ele também poderia usar `<div style="font-size:<?>px"></div>` que daria no mesmo. Só não entendi a necessidade de ter que ser uma Classe

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar as unidades de medidas EM e REM que são baseadas no tamanho da font de seus elementos pais e elemento principal 'body'. O calculo das unidades é feito pela divisão do tamanho da fonte que deseja usar (em px) divido pelo tamanho da fonte de seu elemento pai. Ex.: 16px/16px = 1em(ou rem)

- O **EM**: É baseado em seu elemento pai, segue o exemplo

```html
<div style="font-size: 32px">
  <p style="font-size: 1em">Exemplo em EM.</p> 
</div>
```

Neste exemplo, o paragrafo terá o tamanho tamanho de seu elemento pai "div" que sao 32px, o tamanho de 1em ira equivaler a 32px.

- **REM**: Baseado em seu elemento pai, 'body'. Por padrao este elemento tem 16px. Segue outro exemplo abaixo:

```html
<body style="font-size: 50px">
  <div style="font-size: 32px">
    <p style="font-size: 1rem">Exemplo em REM.</p> 
  </div>
</body>
```

No exemplo acima, o 'p' o 1rem equivalera a 50px, influenciado do elemento 'body'.